# Trying to sum the totals of arguments/parameters entered in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am testing this simple script I wrote that will add all the arguments/parameters that a user enters, and thus provide a sum total.

It sums them all together, but for the life of me, I can't understand why it's always showing the result as a 100's value.

Example:
1+2+3 = 6, yet the result is always 106.

1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21, yet the result is always 121.

As I try higher numbers, it's clear it's not adding them the way I was expecting, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

50+50 = 100, yet the result is 200.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%G in (%*) do (
set /a result+=%%G
echo !result! )
```

Comment: With your code, I get the expected results. What exactly does your command line look like?

Comment: You can try to unset `result` before the `for` loop; `set "result="`.  Looks like it's predefined as `100` (maybe from previous tests)

Answer (score 0):

That's it! I forgot about the undefined behavior of an uninitialized variable. When I ran the script under a new CMD session, it worked correctly. So I set the result variable to 0 to keep it from happening again.